# How to use the fastlane action `environment_variable `

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, fastlane, react-native-config

According to the document of action [environment_variable](http://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/environment_variable/#environment_variable).

I've tried to use it this way in my `Fastfile` but failed.

```rb
environment_variable(set: { ENVFILE: ".env.dev" })     # failed
```

I can not find any example of how to use this action.

I also look into the [source code](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/environment_variable.rb) of this action, but I am not very familiar with ruby.
So I don't know how to pass the parameters.

**Picture of environment_variable action:**
[image]

Now I set the environment variables directly in my `Fastfile` directly and it works, but I still want to know how to use this action.

```rb
ENV["ENVFILE"] = ".env.dev"   # it works
```